# Wrap Flexisel slider into Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs

I try to use [Flexisel](http://9bitstudios.github.io/flexisel/) with Angular but it fails to work somehow.
Here's [plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vs29uLYghZIirZiiYoPT?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('angular.controls.flexSlider', [])

app.directive('flexCarousel', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var options = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
            console.log(options);
            $(element).flexisel(options);               
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked your plunk, please check the fixes there. http://plnkr.co/edit/zH4u3MwkD6HX39I8PFEr?p=preview

You need a template for your directive in first case:

```
var app = angular.module('angular.controls.flexSlider', [])

app.directive('flexCarousel', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude : true,
        template : "<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>",
        scope : {
          options : "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            $('#flexisel').flexisel(scope.options);

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm still  confused with directive. :)